# Add span HTML to woocommerce shop title

Tags: php, html, wordpress, function, woocommerce

How can I add a HTML span to the woocommerce shop title? I have this function to change the shop title to menu but I need to add a 
 and a span.  When I add the html I get an error

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_page_title', 'woo_shop_page_title');
       function woo_shop_page_title( $page_title ) {
                  if( 'Shop' == $page_title) {
                               return "Menu<br><span id="chinese">家庭晚餐</span>";                         }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The double quotes used for the ID attribute of the span tag are breaking your string. Either escape them or switch to single quotes.

Single quote example:

```
return 'Menu<br><span id="...';
```

Escaping example:

```
return "Menu<br><span id=\"...";
```

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Exactly! Thank you Nathan and thank you for the link to the explanation.